# How to write a CSS shorthand Value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I get this CSS declaration:

```
 background: #232222 url("../img/big-team.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
```

In here:

```
$('.class ').css( 'background',  ' //code should be injected here ' );
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why don't you create CSS class and assign it using `$('.class').addClass('CSSClassName');`

Comment: Don't want to be rude but if you had tried putting your CSS property value into the `//code should be injected here` you would have found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and paste your CSS declaration:

```
$('.class').css('background', '#232222 url("../img/big-team.jpg") no-repeat fixed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you use in your css like this:

```
$('.class ').css( 'background',  '#232222 url("../img/big-team.jpg") no-repeat fixed' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by css Shorthand properties

```
   $(".class").css({
          "background-color":"#232222",
          "background-image": "url('../img/big-team.jpg')",
          "background-repeat":"no-repeat",
          "background-position":"fixed"
      });
```